# SELECT FOR UPDATE issue in Spring JDBC app

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, mariadb, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I am using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` statement to achieve row-level locking in my SpringBoot app. Database: MySQL 5.7.28, connector - MariaDb java client 2.5.2, connection pool HikariCP 2.7.9, spring boot version - 2.0.3 Release.

Persistence is accomplished by Spring JDBC Template, not by JPA. I am using Spring Transaction management, annotation-based by slapping `@Transactional` annotation on my DAO methods. Transactional proxies are generated via AspectJ compile-time weaving (`@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)`). I am sure that the transaction manager is configured correctly.

I have written a couple of integration tests that would verify the possibility of a race condition when multiple threads are competing to update the same row, that is supposed to be locked with `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.

Now, the tests work 95% of the time, however, there is one test that is failing when there is a particular sequence of ITs executed.

I am certain that when a test fails, a row lock is not imposed.

I have enabled the MySql query log on the server to help with troubleshooting.

Here is what I see when the first thread is executing the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` statement:

```
2020-01-26T12:54:06.681319Z  1219 Query set autocommit=0
2020-01-26T12:54:36.616097Z  1209 Query SELECT _listed_fields_ FROM _my_table_ WHERE id IN ('19qix6lvsfx') FOR UPDATE
```

It seems that the auto-commit is set on a wrong connection object. Do I read it right? What are those numbers `1219` and `1209`?

When everything works right, the log looks like this:

```
2020-01-26T13:24:22.940787Z  1243 Query set autocommit=0
2020-01-26T13:24:36.515016Z  1243 Query SELECT _listed_fields_ FROM _my_table_ WHERE id IN ('19xbs7vv53r') FOR UPDATE
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I dislike `autocommit=0` because I am likely to forget to `COMMIT` eventually.

`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` only applies if you are in a transaction (autocommit=0 means you are always in a transaction).

Your snippet of the general log implies that all the connections are setting that value, perhaps repeatedly.  No, each connection is unaffected by the setting for other connections.

Do you see any COMMITs in the log?  Do you ever issue ROLLBACK?

Comment: the autocommit=0 query is issued by spring jdbc when @Transactional annotation is encountered. It switches the transaction into a "manual" mode. I do see commits and there are no rollbacks. 
I guess I understand the problem better, in my integration testing, for some reason, framework is creating a bean of Datasource several times, which entails creation of several hikari connection pools. Those connection pools are not closed after individual integration test is finished. So, I see connections borrowed from wrong connection pools. That's why autocommit does not have any impact.